# excel multiple checkbox selection automation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet,
The user can select as many task scenarios as they want, once they are done I want to automate the responses separating it by task.

For examples there are check boxes with following tasks:

- Make bed
- brush teeth
- mop floor
- fold laundry

Then once the user selects the tasks they are looking for an out put below will show: (comma's separate cells)

Make Bed
Who's responsible, how do they make the bed, how long should it take the bed

Brush Teeth
Who's responsible, how do they brush their teeth, how long should it take to brush teeth

etc.

I currently have a macro set up that when a user selects check boxes, I put in a formula that states if checked then show "xxxx" and hard coded in each cell for each task) issue is when not all check boxes are checks then there are blank cells and bottom ones could get lost, and does too nice option since the formula states if its not checked its blank.

Another nice to have would be having user selecting task and user group, that way I could show that user groups tasks for that task as opposed to many task items for the overall task that are irrelevant to the user. I hope its clear.

Comment: Please show the code you already have tried. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I did a simple macros with this formula- I do not have code and I am trying to figure out how to make this be more dynamic. I am assuming VBA would be an option as well as a pivot table but cant seem to get the output I need or want. This is the formula I have: =IF(A4=TRUE, "XXXX", IF(A4=FALSE, " "))

Comment: @DebraHeinrich If you have multiple checkboxes, you may want to use a loop to cycle through checkboxes, or have an array with the names of each checkbox and cycle through it.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991201/excel-vba-how-to-loop-through-checkboxes-based-on-name as a starting point.

Comment: thanks! just needed some inspiration!